# Regular expression extract short match

Tags: php, regex

I am new to regular expression.

The contents is

`">blablabla</a> </td>blablabla "> 8.8GB </a> </td>`

I want to get the value `8.8`, but if i use `(?<=">)(.*?)(?=GB<\/a>)`, it will get the texts before 8.8 as well, ie. `">blablabla</a> </td>blablabla "> 8.8GB`

I don't know how to solve this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If your string is html, use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) instead of regex

Comment: [The force of regex and HTML together in the same conceptual space will destroy your mind like so much watery putty.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483)

Comment: thank you chris85, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[MKG]B
```

to extract the integer value before the storage unit.

The `\d` is any number.
`+` is a quantifier allowing 1 or more numbers.
`?:` is a non-capturing group.
`\.` is a literal `.`. 
 `?` makes the decimal part (`\.\d+`) optional.
 `[MKG]` is a character class allowing `M`, `K`, or `G`. `B` is a literal `B`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/3TifGy/1

PHP Usage:

```
<?php
preg_match('/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[MKG]B/', '">blablabla</a> </td>blablabla "> 8.8GB </a> </td>', $match);
echo $match[1];
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/656562